# With bazel how to create a tar files with individual jar files

Tags: java, bazel

I'd like to create a tar file for java project X that depends on libraries Y & Z with structure like

```
bin/runx (from src/main/scripts)
lib/x.jar (the compiled contents of src/main/java)
lib/y.jar (a maven_jar X depends on)
lib/z.jar (a maven_jar X depends on) 
conf/x (from src/main/resources/conf/x)
```

Is this supported by any of the built in bazel rules?  Is this something I would need to write my self in skylark or bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working in a pretty horrible way.

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/bazel/BUILD

I couldn't find a nice way to expand the jar files required by a target.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "bundle-libs",
    package_dir = "lib",
    files = [
      '//src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial',
      '@com_squareup_okhttp3_okhttp//jar',
      '@com_squareup_okhttp3_logging_interceptor//jar',
      '@com_squareup_okio_okio//jar',
      '@com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_databind//jar',
      '@com_fasterxml_jackson_dataformat_jackson_dataformat_yaml//jar',
      '@com_twitter_joauth//jar',
      '@com_google_oauth_client_google_oauth_client_jetty//jar',
      '@com_google_guava_guava//jar',
      '@org_mortbay_jetty_jetty//jar',
      '@com_github_mrmike_ok2curl//jar',
      '@commons_cli_commons_cli//jar',
      '@commons_lang_commons_lang//jar',
      '@commons_io_commons_io//jar',
      '@org_slf4j_slf4j_jcl//jar',
      '@io_airlift_airline//jar',
      '@javax_inject_javax_inject//jar',
    ],
    mode = "0644",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "bundle-alpn",
    package_dir = "alpn",
    files = ["@alpn_boot//jar"],
    mode = "0644",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "bundle-bin",
    package_dir = "bin",
    files = glob(["src/main/scripts/**"]),
    mode = "0755",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "oksocial-bundle",
    extension = "tgz",
    deps = [
        ":bundle-bin",
        ":bundle-libs",
        ":bundle-alpn",
    ],
)
```

Comment: I think the nice way would be to use skylark to implement this in the DSL instead of bash.

Answer (score 0):

pkg_tar should support that, see http://bazel.io/docs/be/pkg.html#pkg_tar

Comment: I had it mostly working with pkg_tar. But I couldn't get it to insert the dependant jars. I ended up iterating to this point. Do you know how to get that working with pkg_tar without relisting dependencies?

Comment: going back to pkg_tar worked, but I'm still stuck relisting dependencies at the moment.