# How to package bazel project when it depends on @bazel_tools?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have an [example bazel project](https://github.com/vovani/bazel_examples/tree/main/ex_package) that I want to package as tar (to further distribute through homebrew etc...). The project consists of some python files, and a a run shell script.

When trying to use [rules_pkg](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg), I run into the following problem - the run script, [b.sh](https://github.com/vovani/bazel_examples/blob/main/ex_package/b.sh), depends on `@bazel_tools/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash` to resolve the location of the binary package. `@bazel_tools` is not provided by default when using `@rules_pkg`.

What would be the correct approach for creating a distribution of the project above?

Comment: Found this references [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816600/with-bazel-how-to-create-a-tar-files-with-individual-jar-files) [#2](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5518)